# Nunit parallel attributes in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nunit

I have very simple question but can't find in Google any information about it.

I use NUnit3 and NunitAdapter to run my tests through Visual Studio or dotnet test on build agents. I need to add attributes `[assembly: Parallelizable()]` and `[assembly: LevelOfParallelism()]`.

But netCore project haven't assemblyInfo.cs and I don't know where to add this attributes. Where it should be placed?

P.S: I had never worked with netCore before, we migrated to it few days ago.

Comment: You can just add a file and call it `AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: Thank you it really work. I don't know that [assembly: ] can be placed in any .cs file.

Comment: SauceLabs seems to ignore the LevelOfParallelism. I set it to 4 and it runs 5 tests in parallel, the maximum of my OpenSauce account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place that attribute in any file you like, it doesn't have to be `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Having said that, I like to keep these things separate or they become easy to miss so I would advise you keep them in a distinct file, and probably call it `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Answer (score 3):

As explained [into NUnit documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute) you can specify Parallelizable Attribute at test level

- **ParallelScope.Self** = the test itself may be run in parallel with other tests
- **ParallelScope.Children** = child tests may be run in parallel with one another
- **ParallelScope.Fixtures** = fixtures may be run in parallel with one another

For example

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
```

Or alternatively, you can add a file and call it `AssemblyInfo.cs`